# Over-releasing CGContextRef?

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I'm having an issue with a CGContextRef being over-released but I can't figure out where. The documentation says that a CGContextRef created with CGBitmapContextCreate should be released yet when I do I get the error "*** -[Not A Type class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x613d750"

Here's my code:

```
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));


CGContextRelease(ctx); // PROBLEM HERE
```

As you can see, not much happens here apart from rotating the image and creating a UIImage. Any ideas why this is happening?

EDIT:

I've reduced the sample code down to 2 lines and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is not released together with the release of CGImageRelease. I don't remember the exact issue I was having once, but it was a problem with UIImage releasing the context. Try to comment out CGImageRelease(cgimg); and see if CGContextRelease(ctx); works after that.

Comment: I tried commenting out CGImageRelease but I still get the same error on CGContextRelease.

Comment: Just for the test purpose try to comment out CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx); and UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg]; lines as well. I don't have my iOS project here, so i can not look for more details. It might be that the autorelease of the UIImage releases the context for the second time.

Comment: That is interesting, the error still occurs with those lines commented out. In fact to reduce the possibilities I released the ctx immediately after creating it and I still see the error. I will update the question.

Comment: It is interesting indeed. My last suggestion here is to make sure that you recompiled the updated project before re-deployment to the device.

Comment: Yeah, I've cleaned and rebuilt the project a number of times as this doens't make sense but still the same result.